# Chain css media and container queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, container-queries

How can I combine queries like this so I dont repeat css code? Every query works on its own but not together.

I want media to be used as fallback if container queries dont work. I know media is applied to whole page width, while container queries only to element width.

```css
.card-container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: mvp_dialog_data;
}

@container mvp_dialog_data (max-width: 1250px),
@media (max-width: 1250px) { 
   .links {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    
      <div class="meta">
        <span class="time">5:30</span>
      </div>
      <div class="notes">
        <div class="links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want you only need to **move** your `@media` query **into** your `@container`:

```css
.card-container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: mvp_dialog_data;
}

@container mvp_dialog_data (max-width: 1250px){
  @media (max-width: 1250px) { 
   .links {
        display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="meta">
        <span class="time">5:30</span>
      </div>
      <div class="notes">
        <div class="links">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want any of them to be valid, since container queries are not fully supported while media is. Will this work as such?

Comment: Please look for [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries#fallbacks_for_container_queries) in the official MDN web docs.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant, I want media to be used as fallback if container queries dont work. I know media is applied to whole page width, while container queries only to element width. But your answer doesnt seem to do that, if I set max-width: 900px; on .card-container, mvp_dialog_data is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine the @media and @container at-rules. To the best of my knowledge, a proper CSS-only fallback will have to provide separate styles.

```css
/* Fallback */
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .links {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Container queries */
@container mvp_dialog_data (max-width: 1250px) {
  .links {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Feature detection */
@supports (container-type: inline-size) {
  .container {
    container: mvp_dialog_data / inline-size;
  }
}
```

Comment: I came to same conlusion while testing. Is this line necessary and what can happen if its not present?  @supports (container-type: inline-size) {

Comment: I suppose it’s not strictly necessary in this particular case as an invalid declaration will be ignored. But if you intend to add styles to `.container` that will interfer with the fallback, you should wrap them in a feature query.

Comment: And by _invalid_ I refer to unsupported browsers not recognizing the property and treating it as if it was invalid.